# how to make two workstations communicate using straight through cable

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable

Two different workstations are connected with straight through cable. Attempts to ping between hosts are unsuccessful.what should be done to make them communicate?

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by straight-through cable? If the hosts have 1 Gb ports, they should have Auto-MDIX which allows straight-through or crossover cables. If at least one of the hosts supports Auto-MDIX , it should work, but if neither host supports Auto-MDIX, you will need a crossover cable.

Comment: Is the link light on (that little green light on the ethernet card, which lights up, when you plug in a cable connected at the other end)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Most computers support auto mdi-x which means that they will work with both crossover and straight-through cables.

To ping between the 2 PCs, you need to check the following:

- NIC link lights, are they both up?
- Are both computers assigned an IP on the same subnet? You don't have a dhcp server so you will need to either assign a static IP or use a link local address.
- Is there a firewall restricting ICMP packets? Windows 7 blocks incoming ICMP by default.

Comment: this is a good answer